# Paper cylinder inside out

Tags: geometry, surfaces

My question is related with paper folding:

> Given a cylinder of paper it is possible to turn it inside out using folding along lines.

This is a Martin Gardner recreational puzzle.

Secondly, Has anyone proven that it's impossible to turn a cone inside out using straight line foldings?

Any reference to look at?

Comment: I mean, in both cases a FINITE number of straight lines

Comment: It's easy for a short wide cylinder (i.e. a long narrow looped ribbon) of paper. I think that the mathematical question here is: What is the longest cylinder (in relation to its diameter) that can be inverted by folding and unfolding?